# How to allow users to choose between import random and import secrets for generating passwords

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have it so the user can pick between two options "auth" for authenticator passwords and "simp" for simple passwords. the idea is that auth will use secrets and simp will use random.

the option code looks like:

```
options = ['auth', 'simp']

user_input = ''

msg = "Pick an option:\n"
for index, item in enumerate(options):
    msg += f'{index+1}) {item}\n'

while user_input.lower() not in options:
    user_input = input(msg)
```

and then the password generator code looks like this:

```
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))                      
low = string.ascii_lowercase
up = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
sym = "@#$%&*/?"
all = low + up + num + sym
ath = ''.join(auth.choice(all) for i in range(length)) 
smp = "".join(simp.sample(all, length))
password = user_input

print("\nYour Generated Password is :",'\n',password)
```

i am not sure how to get it to know that the options changes it cause i'll choose auth and then 100 ( max for random is 70) and it'll throw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\weeab\cmd\#Simple and Auth Password.py", line 29, in <module>
    smp = "".join(simp.sample(all, length))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\random.py", line 482, in sample   
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

i tried moving things around rewording things i am new to this so i am unsure how everything works..

Comment: lol is it even possible? so lost man

Comment: `all` is the name of a function in Python. Use a different name such as `all_chars`. What is `simp`? What value did you input for length? Why not use `string.punctuation` for `sym`? You could even do `all_chars = string.printable.replace(string.whitespace, '') + ' '`. But the real problem is `password = user_input` which just sets the password to "auth" or "simp". You could use an `if` statement to choose between the two password generation methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random as simp 
import secrets as auth  


if options[int(user_input) - 1] == "authenticator password":
        password = ''.join(auth.choice(scram) for i in range(length))
    else:
         password = "".join(simp.sample(scram, length))
```